# CyberPanel OpenLiteSpeed: Host Node JS Website

Tags: node.js, vps, cyber-panel

I bought my own VPS and installed CyberPanel. Now I want to host my application written in NodeJS (Typescript).

So I have uploaded my application into `public_html` folder:

[image]

The application is resulted from these commands:

```
"build": "tsc --project ./&&copyFiles www/* build",
"build-deploy": "npm run build && cp package*.json build && cd build && npm install --only=production",
```

I use the `build-deploy` npm run command to include the `node_modules` folder as well. The problem is that my website cannot be accessed. It gives a timeout error, it keeps loading the page, then a timeout error shows up.

> Request Timeout This request takes too long to process, it is timed
> out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact
> administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

This is my `vHost Conf`:

```
docRoot                   $VH_ROOT/public_html
vhDomain                  $VH_NAME
vhAliases                 www.$VH_NAME
adminEmails               xxxxxx@gmail.com
enableGzip                1
enableIpGeo               1

index  {
  useServer               0
  indexFiles              index.php, index.html
}

errorlog $VH_ROOT/logs/$VH_NAME.error_log {
  useServer               0
  logLevel                WARN
  rollingSize             10M
}

accesslog $VH_ROOT/logs/$VH_NAME.access_log {
  useServer               0
  logFormat               "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i""
  logHeaders              5
  rollingSize             10M
  keepDays                10  
  compressArchive         1
}

scripthandler  {
  add                     lsapi:apidi5248 php
}

extprocessor apidi5248 {
  type                    lsapi
  address                 UDS://tmp/lshttpd/apidi5248.sock
  maxConns                10
  env                     LSAPI_CHILDREN=10
  initTimeout             600
  retryTimeout            0
  persistConn             1
  pcKeepAliveTimeout      1
  respBuffer              0
  autoStart               1
  path                    /usr/local/lsws/lsphp81/bin/lsphp
  extUser                 apidi5248
  extGroup                apidi5248
  memSoftLimit            2047M
  memHardLimit            2047M
  procSoftLimit           400
  procHardLimit           500
}

phpIniOverride  {

}

module cache {
 storagePath /usr/local/lsws/cachedata/$VH_NAME
}

rewrite  {
 enable                  1
  autoLoadHtaccess        1
}

context /.well-known/acme-challenge {
  location                /usr/local/lsws/Example/html/.well-known/acme-challenge
  allowBrowse             1

  rewrite  {

  }
  addDefaultCharset       off

  phpIniOverride  {

  }
}


vhssl  {
  keyFile                 /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.digilifesoftware.com/privkey.pem
  certFile                /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.digilifesoftware.com/fullchain.pem
  certChain               1
  sslProtocol             24
  enableECDHE             1
  renegProtection         1
  sslSessionCache         1
  enableSpdy              15
  enableStapling           1
  ocspRespMaxAge           86400
}

context / {
  type                    appserver
  location               $VH_ROOT/public_html
  startupFile             server.js
  binPath                 /usr/bin/node
  appType                 node
  maxConns                100
 
  accessControl  {
    allow                 *
  }

  rewrite  {

  }
  addDefaultCharset       off
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Check this file `/usr/local/lsws/logs/stderr.log`. It's node errors log, maybe you`ll find something useful)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33727796)